# Including header files into static library

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, header-files, static-linking

Since every time when we link against a static library we also need to include the header files, I am wondering if it is possible to archive into the static library, when creating it, those heads?

Say I have two object files `foo1.o` and `foo2.o` generated by

```
gcc foo1.c -I foo1.h -c -o foo1.o
gcc foo2.c -I foo2.h -c -o foo2.o
```

Gcc tutorials tell us we can generate `libfoo.a` using

```
ar libfoo.a foo1.o foo2.o
```

This must sound silly, but is it possible to put those header files inside libfoo.a when archiving? In this way, when *linking* against `libfoo.a`, people no more need to spend hours in order to find and *include* `foo1.h` and `foo2.h`, so there seems to be some benefits in doing so, right?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: It's *possible* to put any kind of file into an archive, but manually unpacking them and including them from where they unpack doesn't seem like a better solution.

Comment: @Paul The whole process could have been automated, Paul, if gcc people had that design in minds. The question is why they did not. There should be a reason, a very good one, that gcc guys decided to not save people's time for locating the headers, right?

Comment: You don't have to locate the header if you install the library correctly. You just `#include` it, and it works.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths It seems it does not work that way, Paul. We still need to locate the header? Let me try an example now and reply to you shortly.

Comment: *You* might. I never do. When I install the library properly, I just `#include` it, and it works.

Comment: @Paul. I just tried. I did need to locate the header and use "-I <header-path>", otherwise gcc gives an error saying it cannot find the header. Strange. Let me wait for others response.

Comment: Are you cross-compiling?

Comment: That'll be because you're not installing it properly. If you're installing a library for general use, you ought to put the headers in a path that gcc will automatically search, like `/usr/include`, or `/usr/local/include`, or a custom path that `C_INCLUDE_PATH` references.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel What do you mean by cross-compiling? I write the program on a linux VM and compile on it. I suppose the process is not cross-compiling.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths You cannot install when you have are not root. But you may still want to use that static library.

Comment: @zell: Sure you can. Set up `/home/zell/include/` or whatever you want, put your headers in there, and set `C_INCLUDE_PATH` to point at it in one of your login scripts. You just need to use your tools correctly, instead of look for suboptimal solutions. It's no different from installing the library itself.

Comment: @Paul Agreed. Yes, that is a work-around. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the header is required to compile your source, not to link it. You do not need the header to link your objects with static libraries.

Second, no, there is no standard or common way to generate an archive with both the library and it's header. Probably there is no way to do this with common C compilers.

You could declare the library's prototypes inside your source, and than ignore the header. But this would be unsafe, since there will be no guarantee that both library and you source where compiled with compatible prototypes.

Following `Paul Griffiths` comments. If you just want to not have to include a path for every library, you should install those headers and those libraries and set the path in you environment.

Example:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/install/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/install/lib
```

You must export this every time you open an new shell, or you can define it in you `.bashrc`

Comment: But we do need to locate the header files and use "-I <Location of foo1.h> <Location of foo2.h>" when you want to link against generate an app that  links to foo.a, right?

Comment: Compile and link are different things. You need the header because you use the `#include` statement in you source file. The compiler makes use of the header to discover the libraries prototypes. Once your compilation is done, you need to link your objects with your library, now you use the linker, not the compiler. Gcc does boths jobs for you, but it still are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile everything you want into a static library, but the counterpart is that you won't be able to call the functions from outside (ie by linking) because if you want to do so, you'll always need their prototypes